# Create method for 24 hour time format

Tags: c#, algorithm, methods

I am trying to create C# method with two int arguments

```
public void Time(int hours, int minutes)
```

which satisfies all the following Test Cases:

```
Time(11, 7), returns: "11:07"
Time(24, 0), returns: "00:00"
Time(26, 0), returns: "02:00"
Time(0, 160), returns "02:40" (since 160 minutes = 2 hours and 40 minutes)
Time(-1, 0), returns: "23:00"  (negative number - counterclockwise)
Time(1, -40), returns: "00:20"
Time(-25, -160), returns: "20:20"
```

My inadequate attempt was this:

```
if (hours > 23)
{
    hours %= 24; 
}

if (minutes > 59)
{
    minutes %= 60;
}
```

But this barely satisfied first,second and third conditions only.

Comment: Can you post the entire `Time` method, and more explicitly state the rules the method must follow?

Comment: Your method's return-type is `void`  so it shouldn't be returning anything.  If you meant so less obvious form of "returns", the what is the datatype of that?

Comment: string. So basicially when someone inputs 26 for int hours and 0 for int minutes it should return "02:00". I am more interested in the algorithm in this case. I am still struggling to implement :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel - use `TimeSpan` instead:

```cs
public void Time(int hours, int minutes)
{
    var time = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
    Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Today + time).ToString("HH:mm"));
}
```

Comment: @gunr2171 `Today` is only used to get `00:00` in the time portion. I could have just as well used `new DateTime(2525,1,1)` instead.... What edge case do you expect to get from using `Today`?

Comment: Thank you very much. This certainly solves the problem. I beleive I am not allowed to use TimeSpan but this is still very helpful.

Comment: Ah, so this is a homework assignment... In that case, I would suggest comparing the value of `5 % 24` with `29 % 24`, to see why your conditions are redundant. Use integer division to get hours from minutes and you're pretty much home free. I'm not going to write the code for you because it will teach you nothing.